# When scaling down a universe, what is scaled down, and how to calculate gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, units, celestial-mechanics, scaling

Assume I want to scale down Earth so that it fit into a 500x500 units (pixels) cartesian plane, at a scale of 1:1,000,000.

Earth, with a radius of 6,371,000 meters, now has a radius of 6.371 units. The Moon has a radius of 1.7374 units, and is 384.4 units from Earth.

How exactly does the mass scale down from this? I want to simulate gravity between these two bodies (assuming these two bodies begin with a velocity of 0) do I also need to scale down my gravitational constant? Scaling down using the same factor gives Earth a mass of 5,972,000,000,000,000,000, which doesn't seem right whatsoever, but I am stuck on how else to do this. Does this have something to do with my objects being 2D? I assumed it wouldn't affect anything, as I would just ignore the $z$ axis.

Any advice or links to similar questions would be greatly appreciated (I haven't exactly been able to find an answer to this on stack exchange, but I assume I'm searching for the wrong thing.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it, or possibly underthinking it. You've just adopted a convention of writing distances in megameters instead of meters. As long as you retain your units in your calculations the laws of physics will work. If you don't retain your units in your calculations, the laws of physics won't work no matter what units you choose.

Scaling your universe won't help at all. A universe in which the meter is much "smaller" (and the laws of physics that relate meters to everything else are unchanged) is *exactly identical* to the universe in which the meter is much "larger" (and the laws of physics that relate meters to everything else are unchanged).

Comment: Thanks that clears up a lot of headaches.